# Causal reasoning(implicit models?) vs grammar of native language

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, rationality, linguistics

I was reading about [linguistic relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity) and it struck me that there could also be differences in multilingual individuals and mono/bi-lingual individuals on how they derive/reason/create structure out of the environment ([causality models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality#Theories)).

Anyway, my question can be split as :

1. **Are there standard/widely accepted experiments have been done to test methods used by individuals to infer cause and effect?** Couple
   of  examples for what i have in mind is [here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1914185?uid=3738256&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21101477174411) and [here.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010027796007159)
2. Is there consensus on correlation between these experiments and indication of causal models used?
3. If so, have there been studies of those experiments across monolingual, bilingual and multilingual individuals?

Comment: @JoshGitlin: I did a quick search on google scholar, and realized there's a lot more i have to read just to get this question more clear. Will do that once i get some free time. In fact i don't think i saw any established experimental paradigm for causal models used by people.

Comment: My initial search and skim suggests that the answers are no to all three questions, but i shall wait.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but awfully broad.

Comment: Hmm.. broad?..ok, how would you make it narrower? I thought I made it as specific as i could.

Comment: You say yourself that you're conflating many factors of language differences and split the question into multiple sub-questions--personally, I'd narrow those lists considerably by picking the factors of greatest interest.

Comment: I almost voted to close this for being unclear, but since the author is still active, I think you could greatly simplify this question by simply restating it to be about the evidence for cognitive differences in bi/multilingual persons. There is substantial research on this, but I would say the question has no scientific answer as is.

Comment: @ChristianHummeluhr: Am not comfortable phrasing it as broad as cognitive differences.  I do agree there might not be scientific answer at the moment, but it's not never gonna be answered question.